# Microsoft Azure AD authentication giving 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException'

Tags: c#, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, adal

I am facing a strange imtermittent issue with Azure AD authentication.

We are using CORS enabled web api in our project (origins are specified in web.config which are fetched by custom attribute, and this attribute is used for controllers).

Athorization part is done using adal.js

code is as follows:

startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(test.testapi.WebApi.Startup))]

namespace Test.testapi.WebApi
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {   
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.auth.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Configuration;
using Owin;
using System.Net;

namespace test.testapi.WebApi
{
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //Following line is not required if you are using HTTPS calls to APIs
        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;


        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
            });
    }

}
}
```

When the control goes to startup.auth.cs it gives System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AS5s.png)

Now thing is while i was working on my local dev environment i never got this issue(always authenticated fine ) but QA was facing this issue on QA server, so we started hosting web api from my machine, After which i also started getting this issue and that too quite frequently now.

what is this issue if anyone has faced this same issue.

Comment: You might try watching the traffic in fiddler and seeing where this 401 is coming from.

Comment: It seems that the request is failing to retrieve metadata. This is the metadata address used: https://login.windows.net/{0}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml where {0} is replaced by your tenant id. Can you go to this url after replacing your tenant id in a browser and see if you get any results?

Comment: sorry guys but i haven't encountered this issue in last 2 days, i will surely try your suggestions if i encounter this error again.